# Ubuntu To Be Used to Review Bad Disk/Sector

Tags: installation, hard-drive, data-recovery

The reason I want to install Ubuntu is that I was informed I could use it to review a disk that Windows is having issues accessing. I am not sure if that is because of a bad disk sector or if Windows is mentally failing at accessing it or what. Here's my plan and I need assistance in what I should be doing:

1. Ext HDD has 172 folders: all but one is available to me in Windows. I can see the inaccessible one, but I can't move data from it, open the folder, etc (whether using DOS, Windows Explorer or WinRoboCopy)
2. I want to use Ubuntu to try and access that External HDD and that specific folder so I can safely move the files (important files).

So, I need to install Ubuntu - but where? I do not plan on using it (yet) as my primary operating system and am not looking for Dual-Boot even (at least not yet). Do I install it on my laptop hard drive? Can I install it on a thumb drive as some have suggested?

I have Ubuntu Desktop downloaded (nothing installed anywhere yet though). That's all I've done, but I really have no idea what to do next. I would consider myself an intermediate techy (although you may not think so from this explanation).

Any guidance / assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to install Ubuntu anywhere. Just write it to a thumb drive with the help of [this howto](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), or to a DVD with [this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Burning_from_Windows), and then boot from that device. On the second thought, have you tried running the CHKDSK check from Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to view the files on the hard drive just from the Ubuntu live CD/DVD or USB Flash. Select 'try linux without installing' option.

After the Ubuntu starts, it should be visible from the File Manager - no guarantees, of course, but Nautilus should be able to read the file system present and mount it automatically.